# Adding nice transitions when updating a collection with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wonder how can I add some effects when updating a collection

`<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterFunction">

{{item.name}}

</li>`

**items** is a collection, 30 for example.

This list only shows items that verify the **filterFunction**.
The scope is regulary updated.

It works, but it's a bit violent!

Adding **transitions** with jquery could be great (fade in and fade out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the animate directive in angular-ui

http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-animate

It should help you achieve what you are trying to do. Just to let you know, the angular team has promised animations support for ng-repeat and ng-switch in the next or so major release. So keep your fingers crossed till then.

Comment: It seams to be what I am looking for, thanks. I'll also look forward for the future versions!

Comment: Animated removal would've been nice as well, however for now this will do it.

Comment: Angular now supports animations natively (ngAnimate)

Answer (score 12):

I recommend you use the new ngAnimate directive provided in the AngularJS Core.
It supports removal and is somewhat nicer to work with.

Read the documentation [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate). Read more about it on [this awesome yearofmoo tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Comment: [ngAnimate API Reference](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate)

Answer (score 2):

here's a decent article on the ngAnimate features and usage: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

A lot of a nice transtions at this site:

[AnuglarJS Animations](http://www.nganimate.org/)